# Flutter - Make widgets share space in a stack

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create a behavior similar to what you would get in a column, where one widget is expanded (widget1) and the other one takes as little space as possible.

See this picture:
[image]

However this needs to be in a stack, as I intend to make the bottom widget overlap the top one as it opens (like a sheet).

My current implementation is telling widget 1 to take 3/4 of the screen and widget 2 to take 1/4, but I want to make widget 2 only takes as much space as needed and widget 1 to take the rest.

```
body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: (constraints.maxHeight * 3 / 4) + 12,  // +12 to extend to the corners of widget 2
              child: FlutterMap(
                ... //not important
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: SuggestionBottomSheet(
                peekHeight: constraints.maxHeight / 4,
                maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }),
```

Maybe by knowing the size of widget 2 `widget2Height` I can tell widget 1 to take `constraints.maxHeight - widget2Height + 12`

Any ideas?